# I am inserting millions of records in a table and in other session I want to know the status of the same

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am inserting millions of records in a table 
In other session I want to know the status of the same that is how many records have been processed, 
No commit is issued in first session

Comment: Are you doing a single `INSERT` statement that inserts millions of rows?  Or are you running a loop that runs millions of single-row `INSERT` statements?

Comment: using a loop to insert a record ...if possible provide answers in both scenarios with some explanation

Comment: without some kind of commit it is impossible

Answer (score 3):

Query [`v$session_longops`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2092.htm). Not 100% but gives a good sense of the session state.

Answer (score 2):

If you have oracle 11g i propose usage of DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE package which allows you to create task chunks and monitoring the process flow (in your case number processed rows). I found tutorial resolving similar case to your situation: http://www.oraclefrontovik.com/2013/05/getting-started-with-dbms_parallel_execute/

Answer (score 1):

Create a procedure with pragma `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` which update your counters in another table. Other sessions will see the counters but your main session still not commit. 
You may update the counter when you reach 1000 records or how frequently you need it. Don't forget to update the counters when you rollback in main session.

[example of procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABEECAF)

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing inserts in a loop try this construct:

```
FOR cur IN (SELECT rownum rn, something ... FROM something_else ...)
LOOP
    INSERT INTO somewhere ...
    dbms_application_info.set_module('Doing inserts', cur.rn || ' rows done');
END LOOP;
```

Then check `module` and `action` columns in `v$session` view.

Comment: and by using array fetches it also performs well. If also the target has been setup, v$session_longops will give an estimation as when to reach the target

Answer (score 1):

First, find SQL_ID of Your session in `GV$SQL_MONITOR`. Then use it to find Your query's progress and details:

```
SELECT SQL_ID, status, PROCESS_NAME, FIRST_REFRESH_TIME, LAST_CHANGE_TIME
      ,PLAN_LINE_ID,PLAN_DEPTH,LPAD(' ',PLAN_DEPTH)||PLAN_OPERATION AS OPER
      ,PLAN_OPTIONS, PLAN_OBJECT_NAME, PLAN_OBJECT_TYPE
      ,OUTPUT_ROWS
  FROM GV$SQL_PLAN_MONITOR 
 WHERE SQL_ID IN ( '0u063q75nbjt7' ) -- Your SQL_ID
 order by sql_id,process_name,plan_line_id;
```

Once You found SQL_ID of Your query You can monitor progress in `(G)V$SQL_PLAN_MONITOR` and processed rows in `OUTPUT_ROWS` column.

Comment: +1 You may also want to consider using `select * from table(dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'your sql id', type => 'text'));` for a more user-friendly view of that information.

Answer (score 0):

The status can sometimes be derived from the table's segment size.

This is usually *not* the best approach.  But often times it is too late to add logging, and tools like v$session_longops and SQL Monitoring frequently fail to provide accurate estimates, or any estimates at all.

Estimating by the segment size can be very tricky.  You must be able to estimate the final size, perhaps based on another environment.  Progress may not be linear; some operations may take an hour, and then writing to the table takes the last hour.  Direct-path writes will not write to the table's segment initially, instead there will be a temporary segment with an unusual name.

Start with a query like this:

```
select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 mb
from dba_segments
where segment_name = '[table name]';
```